# istio ingress, how to use gcp self managed certificate?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress, istio, istio-gateway

we're migrating our native ingress to use istio ingress (gateway), in our kubernetes yaml definition, we could define this as an annotation i.e.

```
annotations:
  ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: cert-name
```

Which would use the certificate stored in GCP.

But it seems that this isn't possible when using istio ingress? Any advice?

Comment: I think the prerequisite to using that annotation is to use the Ingress resource. You can continue to use the Ingress resource with Istio (https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/kubernetes-ingress/), but if you want to move to the Gateway resource you'll probably have to store the certificate as a secret in the cluster.